# Python : Employee and Production Worker Classes program, I do not know where my error is?

Tags: python

Hi i do not know were the error is i have looked threw several times and cant seam to find the problem and after hrs of tinkering i do not want to mess it up any more then i have aready.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self,name,number):
        self.__name = name
        self.number = number
    def set_emp_name(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    def set_emp_number(self,number):
        self.__number = number
    def get_emp_name(self):
        return self.__number
    def get_emp_number(self):
        return self.__number

class ProductionWorker(Employee):

    def __init__(self,name,number,shift_num,pay_rate):
        Employee.__init__(self,name,number)
        self.__shift_num = shift_num
        self.__pay_rate = pay_rate
    def set_shift_num(self,shift_num):
        self.__shift_num = shift_num
    def set_pay_rate(self,pay_rate):
        self.__pay_rate = pay_rate
    def get_shift_num(self):
        return self.__shift_num
    def get_pay_rates(self):
        return self.__pay_rate

def main():

    print('enter following Details of the Employee')
    name = input ('Enter Employee Name: ')
    number = input ('Enter Employee Number: ')
    sh= input ('Enter Shift Number: ')
    pay = input ('Enter Pay Rate: ')

    emp = ProductionWorker(name,number,sh,pay)

    print ('Details of Employee:')
    print ('Name',emp.get_emp_name())
    print ('Employee Number',emp.get_emp_number())
    print ('Shift Number',emp.get_shift_number())
    print ('Pay Rate',emp.get_pay_rate())


main()
```

the output is :

```
enter following Details of the Employee
Enter Employee Name: john
Enter Employee Number: 12
Enter Shift Number: 2
Enter Pay Rate: 10

Details of Employee:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/chapter11probelm1.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/chapter11probelm1.py", line 42, in main
    print ('Name',emp.get_emp_name())
  File "D:/chapter11probelm1.py", line 12, in get_emp_name
    return self.__number
AttributeError: 'ProductionWorker' object has no attribute '_Employee__number'
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AttributeError: 'ProductionWorker' object has no attribute '_Employee__number'

Comment: Hey welcome to SO! Could you edit the title to be more specific? Someone searching to see if they have a similar problem to you wouldn't be helped by this title

Comment: You have some typos. Check `Employee.__init__` for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the runnable code that you can try. I use PyCharm to make me easily spot where the errors are:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self,name,number):
        self.__name = name
        self.number = number
    def set_emp_name(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    def set_emp_number(self,number):
        self.__number = number
    def get_emp_name(self):
        return self.__name
    def get_emp_number(self):
        return self.number

class ProductionWorker(Employee):

    def __init__(self,name,number,shift_num,pay_rate):
        Employee.__init__(self,name,number)
        self.__shift_num = shift_num
        self.__pay_rate = pay_rate
    def set_shift_num(self,shift_num):
        self.__shift_num = shift_num
    def set_pay_rate(self,pay_rate):
        self.__pay_rate = pay_rate
    def get_shift_num(self):
        return self.__shift_num
    def get_pay_rates(self):
        return self.__pay_rate

def main():

    print('enter following Details of the Employee')
    emp_name = input('Enter Employee Name: ')
    number = input('Enter Employee Number: ')
    sh = input('Enter Shift Number: ')
    pay = input('Enter Pay Rate: ')

    emp = ProductionWorker(emp_name, number, sh, pay)

    print ('Details of Employee:')
    print ('Name',emp.get_emp_name())
    print ('Employee Number',emp.get_emp_number())
    print ('Shift Number',emp.get_shift_num())
    print ('Pay Rate',emp.get_pay_rates())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Mind you, that I only make changes that stop the application from running though :)

Comment: don't forget to mark which answer as the accepted answer: which means this question is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Python mangles attribute names that only start with a double underscore with the name of the current class. This breaks inheritance of those attributes. Change attributes that you want to be private to use a single underscore instead.

Answer (score 1):

As the traceback suggests, the error is on line 12 (the last bit of the traceback is the highest part of your stack).

```
def get_emp_name(self):
    return self.__number  # <- This is line 12
```

In the `__init__` for your class (`Employee`), you are defining `self.number`, whereas on line 12, you are accessing `self.__number`. Do you see the problem there?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help the code is now working

class Employee:

```
def __init__(self,name,number):
    self.__name = name
    self.number = number
def set_emp_name(self,name):
    self.__name = name
def set_emp_number(self,number):
    self.__number = number
def get_emp_name(self):
    return self.__name
def get_emp_number(self):
    return self.number
```

class ProductionWorker(Employee):

```
def __init__(self,name,number,shift_num,pay_rate):
    Employee.__init__(self,name,number)
    self.__shift_num = shift_num
    self.__pay_rate = pay_rate
def set_shift_num(self,shift_num):
    self.__shift_num = shift_num
def set_pay_rate(self,pay_rate):
    self.__pay_rate = pay_rate
def get_shift_num(self):
    return self.__shift_num
def get_pay_rates(self):
    return self.__pay_rate
```

def main():

```
print('enter following Details of the Employee')
name = input ('Enter Employee Name: ')
number = input ('Enter Employee Number: ')
sh= input ('Enter Shift Number: ')
pay = input ('Enter Pay Rate: ')

emp = ProductionWorker(name,number,sh,pay)

print ('Deails of Employee:')
print ('Name: ',emp.get_emp_name())
print ('Employee Number: ',emp.get_emp_number())
print ('Shift Number: ',emp.get_shift_num())
print ('Pay Rate: ',emp.get_pay_rates())
```

main()